# Preventing fragment custom animations from playing on screen rotation?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using custom animations in a FragmentTransaction for a Stopwatch fragment of mine. Here's the code:

```
private void addStopWatch() {
    if(_stopwatchFragment == null) {
        _stopwatchFragment = new StopwatchFragment();

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.anim_slide_down, R.anim.anim_slide_up)
                           .add(R.id.ContentContainer, _stopwatchFragment, STOPWATCH_TAG)
                           .commit();

        _stopwatchVisible = true;
    }
}
```

Whenever the screen is rotated, the R.anim.anim_slide_down animation is played again (Here I'm not adding a new fragment, I'm re-attaching the one that already exists). Is there a way to avoid this behaviour and just let the fragment appear along with the activity view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can easily be solved by using a static field in your activity. Declare this as a static member of your activity class:

```
private static boolean hasAnimated = false;
```

And then inside your method you could do this:

```
private void addStopWatch() {
    if(_stopwatchFragment == null) {
        _stopwatchFragment = new StopwatchFragment();

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if(!hasAnimated) {
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.anim_slide_down, R.anim.anim_slide_up)
                               .add(R.id.ContentContainer, _stopwatchFragment, STOPWATCH_TAG)
                               .commit();
            hasAnimated = true
        } else {
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.ContentContainer, _stopwatchFragment, STOPWATCH_TAG)
                               .commit();
        }

        _stopwatchVisible = true;
    }
}
```

Although I'm not sure if this requires proper cleanup on activity destroy. Just to be sure, set hasAnimated to false inside onDestroy().

Comment: Simple and elegant solution, I wish I had thought of it :) Thanks.